# How to rectify pip3 file not found error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have installed python 2 and 3 and also have added the path to system variables. Everything except pip3 is working fine. Pip3 shows a error stating file is not found. Given below is the result I get on command line

Any direct pip3 command shows "The system cannot find the file specified". But if executed with "python3 -m" at the beginning then it runs fine. How can this be fixed so that pip3 can be accessed directly.

```
C:\Users>python3 -m pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from D:\Software\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

Python 2

```
C:\Users>python2
Python 2.7.18 <v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 20 2020, 13:25:05> (MSC v.1500 64 bit <AMD64>] on win32
Type “help”, “copyright”, “credits” or “license” for more information.
>>> quit<>

C:\Users>pip2 —-version
pip 20.2.3 from d:\software\python27\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)
```

Python 3

```
C:\Users>python3
Python 3.8.5 <tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit <Intel>] on win32
Type “help”, “copyright”, “credits” or “license” for more information.
>>> quit<>

C:\Users>pip3 —-version
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "d:\software\python38\python.exe" "D:\Software\Python38\Scripts\pip3.exe" —-version’: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use ``pip3`` instead of the more robust ``python3 -m pip``?

Comment: The `pip`, `pip3`, `pipX.Y`, etc. scripts are unreliable. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/